# What is the difference between parameters & cooficients in Machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, mathematics

**are both terms interchangeable?** 
I'm kinda new to machine learning field and very confused about these terms in machine learning perspective.

Comment: Could you be clearer. In many algorithms, the coefficients are the weights in many algorithms, such as regressions. Are these the same coefficients?

Answer (score -1):

When talking about coefficients, we usually refer to some fixed numbers or constants, e.g. learning rate coefficient is 0.001 and it will not be changed during training. Parameters are usually changing, e.g. model is training to adjust right parameters. However, there are no strict borders between these two notions.

Comment: Depends on the use OP is giving to the word coefficient. He might as well be referring to the coefficients (weights) in a regression